# Non-stop Garbage Collection in 2D surfaceview animation

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, surfaceview

I'm having an issue where the system GC is being called incessantly when running my 2D animation, and I'm not sure why.

Everything I've read has suggested avoiding creating bitmaps in the onDraw() method, which I am not doing, but I still have GC being called about once per second, which is seriously impacting usability on lower-end devices.

The code is very long, so I won't post it all here, but basically, there's a thread that calls
`_surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null)`, then `postInvalidate`, resulting in onDraw() being called, followed by `_surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(_canvas)`.

My onDraw() method has several iterations of `_canvas.drawCircle(...)`, `_canvas.drawBitmap(...)` (drawing a bitmap that was created once when the SurfaceView was created), and a lot of numeric calculations involving `Math.pow(...)`.  The application uses several (10+) Double ArrayLists which it reads and writes to several times in each onDraw() routine.

Can anyone shed some light on why GC is being called so often and what I could do to help?  Am I simply calculating too much and shouldn't expect higher framerates?

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that this issue persists even when I comment out all bitmap drawing and the FPS decreases steadily over time, the longer the animation has been running.

Comment: Have you done any heap profiling? Here is a nice blog post: [Memory Analysis for Android Applications](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link! After running a heap analysis, I see that byte[] arrays are taking up ENORMOUS amounts of memory. I have a 500x500px image I had forgotten was still being created even when I don't draw it to the canvas. When I commented this line out, I got much smaller GC calls (but just as frequent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is because of the use of ArrayList of Double as you comment. Big double *Double* is an object wrapper while *double* is a native. Whenever you switch from Double to double and viceversa in your arithmetic operations a lot of garbage is generated forcing the GC to start collecting a lot of tiny objects that will degrade performance a lot.

In my experience using double[] instead of ArrayList<*Double*> can boost performance significantly

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you're onto the issue. When I remove all bitmap allocations (after doing a memory allocation analysis), I still get GC calls just as frequently, but for much smaller quantities and time, leading me to believe that the Double arraylists are the cause for the frequency, and the bitmap size is the source of the time it requires.